# Expression deduction for energy density per wave length

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavelength

Energy density per frequency is defined by Planck formula as:

$$u(\nu,T)=\frac{8\pi h}{c^3} \frac{\nu^3}{e^{\frac{h\nu}{kT}}-1}$$

The relation between wave length, $\lambda$, and frequency, $\nu$, of a wave on vacuum is given by:

$$c=\lambda \nu$$

And the relation between energy density per frequency, $u(\nu,T)$, and energy density per wave length, $w(\lambda,T)$ is expressed as:

$$w(\lambda,T)d\lambda=u(\nu,T)d\nu$$

So, $w(\lambda,T)=\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}u(\nu,T)$. I've seen in books that it's supposed to be the absolute value of $\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}$, $\left|\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}\right |$ instead of $\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}$ as I wrote on the equation. But why?

Comment: Because the energy density is obviously a positive quantity and whether you integrate from high to low or form low to high values does not matter, only the absolute value of the integration measure matters (as it is usually handled in multi-dimensional integrals, there the transformation formula is also $d^3x = d^3u \left|\det \left(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_j}\right)_{ij}\right|$ because you do not care about the orientation of the basis).

Comment: Because $d\nu/d\lambda$ is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that $\lambda$ is a decreasing function of $\nu$, so that if $d\nu$ is positive then $d\lambda$ is (at least formally) negative, but we explicitly want to not care about that. We want $u(\nu,T)d\nu$ to be the energy content per non-directed unit frequency, and ditto for $w(\lambda,T)d\lambda$, and the absolute value ensures that that is the case.

More specifically, we want to use $u(\nu,T)$ to get the energy content between frequencies $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2>\nu_1$ as
$$
U(\nu_1,\nu_2,T)=\int_{\nu_1}^{\nu_2}u(\nu,T)d\nu
$$
and we similarly want to use $w(\lambda,T)$ to get the energy content between wavelengths $\lambda_2=c/\nu_2$ and $\lambda_1=c/\nu_1>\lambda_2$ (note the changed order) as
$$
W(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,T)=\int_{\lambda_2}^{\lambda_1}w(\lambda,T)d\lambda,
$$
and we want both contents to be equal and positive.

However, if you do the change of variable you get
$$
W(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,T)
=\int_{\lambda_2}^{\lambda_1}w(\lambda,T)d\lambda
=\int_{\nu_2}^{\nu_1}w(\lambda,T)\frac{d\lambda}{d\nu}d\nu
=\int_{\nu_1}^{\nu_2}w(\lambda,T)\left|\frac{d\lambda}{d\nu}\right|d\nu,
$$
with the absolute value coming from the minus sign in switching the limits of integration and the fact that $d\lambda/d\nu$ is negative.